# How to concatenate a string with chrono::milliseconds?

Tags: c++, string, c++-chrono

I need to have a string with timestamp in milliseconds in it.
I got the milliseconds that way (after looking for it here on stackoverflow):

```
milliseconds ms = duration_cast< milliseconds >(
    system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
);
```

now I have to concatenate it like:

```
string = "something " + ms + " something else";
```

Any help?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a way to convert `ms` into a string.  The standard has [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) but that wont work directly with a duration.  To convert the duration to a integral type that `to_string()` can use you need to use the [`count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count) function

```
string = "something " + std::to_string(ms.count()) + " something else";
```

Comment: `ms.count()` works fine if I print it as `%llu`, but if I try to print `std::to_string(ms.count())` as `%s` I get strange characters, like ��

Comment: @Crisoberillo are you using `printf()`?

Comment: (1/2) In my example I probably oversimplified too much. I'm using cocos2d-x to develop a game. I need to handle some network communication and what I must achieve is to format a string like `"ts="+ timestamp + "&a=move"`.

Comment: (2/2) Checking some cocos2d-x guides and stackoverflow, I'm at this point: `const char* postData = ("ts="+ std::to_string(ms.count()) + "&a=move").c_str();`. My current issue is that `postData` is empty, but if I replace ms.count() with a small manually inserted integer, it works fine. If the integer I use is too big (6 digits or more) I again have an empty string. Both 10000 and 99999 works but one more digit, like 100000 and 999999 give me the empty string issue. I hope it's understandable

Comment: @Crisoberillo store the string as a std::string and then if you need a `const char*` you can always call `c_str()`.  `auto timestamp = "ts="+ std::to_string(ms.count()) + "&a=move"; some_function(timestamp.c_str());`

Comment: omg, this works. So the trick is to store `"ts="+ std::to_string(ms.count()) + "&a=move"` inside a variable? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Yes.  you need to make the string persistent as `"ts="+ std::to_string(ms.count()) + "&a=move"` creates a temporary string and it need to be assigned to something if you want to use it after that line.

Answer (score 4):

Use `count` method and `std::to_string`. Example:

```
string = "something " + std::to_string(ms.count()) + " something else"
```