# How to put the value from chrono into the variable

Tags: c++

I had a problem working on the C++ project.
I measured the time it takes for Chrono to execute the code.

```
system_clock::time_point StartTime = system_clock::now();
system_clock::time_point FirstPartEndTime = system_clock::now();
duration<double> DefaultSec = FirstPartEndTime - StartTime;
milliseconds mill = duration_cast<milliseconds>(FirstPartEndTime - StartTime);
```

I want to put the millisecond(mill) values into the variable.
So I tried this.

```
char test[70] = "The required time is as follows :";
char times = mill;
strcat(test, times);
```

But an error occurred.

> 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::chrono::milliseconds' to 'char'

> 'char *strcat(char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char' to 'const char *'

How can I put the millisecond value of chrono into a variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860405/how-to-concatenate-a-string-with-chronomilliseconds)

Comment: Is there any reason you are trying to use C-style `char[]`/`char*`/`strcat` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @user17732522 There is no reason. It was originally a c project, but it was made with cpp because chrono was used.

Comment: @iLittleWizard Thanks for replying. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860405/how-to-concatenate-a-string-with-chronomilliseconds) you provided solved one error, but the other one is still occurring. > 'char *strcat(char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char' to 'const char *' This error is still occurring.

Comment: @Gaon `strcat` is used to concatenate C-style strings, not a single `char`. And you probably don't want to store the value in a `char` anyway.

Comment: @Gaon I assumed `char` was a typo for `char*`. Otherwise I don't really understand the question. You don't need either of the `char` variables or `strcat`. Just use `std::string` as in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you for reply. The reason I used strcat was to insert a string and a variable at the same time while writing a file (fopen, fputs).

Comment: Use C++ file streams and write `stream << "The required time is as follows :" << mill;`. If you're absolutely convinced that C is the future, use `fprintf`.

Comment: @ molbdnilo I did this because I want to write to a file (fopen, fputs), not simply the output (printf).

Answer (score 0):

> 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::chrono::milliseconds' to 'char'
> That error was resolved as given by @iLittleWizard.

> 'char *strcat(char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char' to 'const char *'
> I solved this error by replacing string with char.

For Example :

```
char ch[100];
string a = "This is sentence.";
strcpy(ch,a.c_str());
```

Thanks to @iLittleWizard , @user17732522 , and @Yksisarvinen for the replies.